Meaning of 折れ込む here
I am uncertain about the meaning of 折れ込んだ in this sentence:

大通りから二丁も深く折れ込んだ小路は存外静かであった。

I looked up what it means and I found this definition: ① 内側に折れ曲がる。「奥へ―・んだ路地」 but I still don't understand the concept. What does 折れ込んだ小路 look like?

This is from Soseki's Kokoro, a novel written in 1914. People generally don't use 折れ込む like this today, but I think it means the same thing as 入り組む and 折れ曲がる. Something like "2 cho (≈ 218 m) far from the main avenue" is usually sufficient, but 折れ込む also implies that the route was complex and there were several turns until his destination.

この「丁」って長さの単位（「町」の略字）ではないかと思ったんですがどうですかね？ 1丁=約109m だそうです。https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%94%BA_(%E5%8D%98%E4%BD%8D)#%E9%95%B7%E3%81%95%E3%81%AE%E5%8D%98%E4%BD%8D

@chocolate ありがとうございます。何か違和感を感じてわざわざ明鏡国語辞典引いたのに載ってませんでした… ＞＜

Thank you. I don't get what you mean by "deep from." How 深く is understood? Is it an adverb for 折れ込んだ? Perhaps it's synonymous with 遠い? If so, shouldn't it be 大通りから二丁も深い折れ込んだ小路 instead?

@weeab00 I used "deep" to refer to somewhere distant from the main, busier street/place, and 深い is used in the same sense.

TBH I've never seen "deep from" used like this context. Maybe "far from" sounds better?

Is there any difference between 大通りから二丁も深く折れ込んだ小路 and 大通りから二丁も深い折れ込んだ小路?

@weeab00 Thanks, then let's just use "far". I feel 深い tends to be paired with 折れ込む than with 小路. Likewise, 深い道路 sounds puzzling and 深い迷路 sounds slightly awkward to me, but 深く入り組んだ道路/迷路 sounds perfectly natural.

You seem to use 深い in a different sense here. 深く入り組んだ道路 can also mean very  winding road.

@weeab00 No, 深く入り組んだ道路 is not a single winding road, but rather multiple roads intersecting like a maze.

I'm bit confused about the meaning of 深く in 深く入り組んだ道路. I imagine it as an intertwined set of roads located in the middle of forest or the bottom of a sea?

@weeab00 深く入り組んだ is "heavily/highly intertwined", not "in some deep area". English speakers use "heavy", and Japanese speakers use "deep".

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
